# Detecting background color of an image

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I would like to get some help regarding detection of background color of a jpg image.

I have lot of images in a source directory, and I want to read them on-by-one in my ASP.NET app, and detect if they have a white background or not.

How can I detect the background color?

Comment: You can read every pixel in the image and check which color is more repeated... not the best, but might solve your problem

Comment: ditto @ivowiblo, though it is probably enough just to read the edge pixels.

Answer (score 1):

You couldn't just read the border pixels, that would give misleading results for icons that have a box around the border, e.g. the LoveFilm logo would return red when the answer should be white.

Counting the most repeated color would also be misleading, in the case of, for example the MSDN logo, the background is transparent (as is the border) but the most repeated color would probably be dark blue (I've not counted).

Comment: Perhaps the blue _is_ the background color, and your brain just fails to interpret the right image :) (+1)

Comment: jpeg can't be transparent, and even if it can it's not white, it's transparent :)

Comment: Aye, JPEGs don't have alpha information, they were just examples of images I though most people would know (or easily find) that backed up my point that one rule probably won't suit all scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use the GetPixel function, you can find some doc here : 
[GetPixel Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144909%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You just have to choose the coordinates in order to get a RGB value.

Then, you can try it with as many coordinates as you want to have a lot of value.

Just check your values in order to know if it is white or not.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean if the color of the pixels close to the image borders is white.
Otherwise your formulation is far too vague.

You may check just that, the pixels around the borders are white (you may consider doing some smoothing first to quench noise)

Comment: could you let me know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public bool IsBackgroundWhite(Bitmap theImageBitmap)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(theImageBitmap);
    int weight = 0;

    for (int x=0;x<bmp.Width;x++) {
        weight += GetWeight(bmp.GetPixel(x,0));
        weight += GetWeight(bmp.GetPixel(x,bmp.Height-1));
    }

    for (int y=0;y<bmp.Height;y++) {
        weight += GetWeight(bmp.GetPixel(0,y));
        weight += GetWeight(bmp.GetPixel(bmp.Width-1,y));
    }

    if (weight > 255)
        return true;
    return false;
}

private int GetWeight(Color c)
{
    if (c.R >= 200 && c.B >= 200 && C.G >= 200)
    {
        int n1 = 255 - c.R;
        int n2 = 255 - c.G;
        int n3 = 255 - c.B;

        return (int)((n1+n2+n3) / 3)
    }
}
```

Comment: is this code running through all the pixles on the image? wouldnt that include the image as well as its background? i only want to check background.. so this code dint work on all images.. can you please help?

Comment: @nehaaggarwal - No. This code is only running through the borders of the image. The first `for` loop runs through the top and bottom borders and the second `for` loop runs through the left and right borders. Also, this code uses a "weighted" value, meaning that if the borders were an off white or maybe one of the borders isn't white at all because of a shadow, for example, it would still register as a white border.

Comment: @thatsmeuc: why did you try to edit this post and delete icemanind's code? That's not right.